# Erlang shell ignoring parameters when using path add

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

`erl -sname test –pa ./simple_cache/ebin` used to work perfectly fine (and I'm in the correct dir), but now:

```
Eshell V11.1.5 
1> node().
nonode@nohost
```

Neither the net kernel is started nor the path is added. Doing so manually in the shell works though.

Comment: I can replicate and the problem seems to be the path, since running just `erl -sname test` does work as expected (i.e. it sets the node name).

Comment: How can this be ? I'm getting no error and the path's contents are fine: 
$ ls ./simple_cache/ebin

create_tables.beam
      sc_app.beam
             sc_element_sup.beam
     sc_event_logger.beam
    sc_sup.beam
             simple_cache.beam
resource_discovery.beam 
sc_element.beam
sc_event.beam
sc_store.beam
simple_cache.app

Comment: Yeah… no idea. I'm also interested in figuring this out now.

Comment: So I boiled it down to this: I'm literally running the same commands, but one is copied from slack and the other one is typed (don't know anymore which one was which though): https://giphy.com/gifs/FuEYwhAdTDvoKi3efj one works, the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash in `–pa` is not a regular dash but something else. Some fancy formatting gone wrong before it was copied probably.

The `–pa` is code point (aka dash) (U+2013) and `-sname` is code point (U+002D) (aka hyphen-minus).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the dashes in the command are different for whatever reason:

```
erl -sname test –pa ./simple_cache/ebin
```

The one before `sname` is slightly shorter, using that one turns out to solve the issue. my god.